# ASP.NET malfunction when signing up to an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, event-handling

We are two students who are trying to develop a website with asp.net functions. We have come to this issue:

We have a booking page where a logged in user can sign up to events, we have made a separate tabel for handling the sign ups.

In this table we have The Member_id which we get from session, and the event id.

We then continue to check for member_id and the event_id in the database to make sure that the same member cant sign up to the same event twice.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Medlems_id"] == null)

        Response.Redirect("medlemslogin.aspx");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["RedirectedMessage"] != null)
        {
            lblmessage.Text = Session["RedirectedMessage"].ToString();
            Session["RedirectedMessage"] = null;
        }
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Få fat i Hold_id fra den valgte kolonne og gem det i variablen varHold_id
    var varHold_id = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[6].Text;

    //DB CONNECTION 
    string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\drt.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
    OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);

    MyConn.Open();

    OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);

    Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE Hold_ID = @Hold_idPar";
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Hold_idPar", varHold_id);

    OleDbDataReader ObjReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (ObjReader.Read())
    {
        var antalPladser = Convert.ToInt32(ObjReader["Pladser"]);
        var antalTilmeldte = Convert.ToInt32(ObjReader["Tilmeldte"]);
        var holdnavn = Convert.ToString(ObjReader["Hold"]);
        var Medlems_idva = Session["Medlems_id"];



        if (antalPladser > 0)
        {


            OleDbCommand dbcmd = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);
            dbcmd.CommandText = "Select Hold_id FROM Tilmelding WHERE Hold_id = @Hold_idPar AND Medlems_id = @Medlems_idPar";
            dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Medlems_idPar", Medlems_idva);
            dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Hold_idPar", varHold_id);



            OleDbDataReader ValReader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (ValReader.Read())
            {
                lblmessage.Text= "Du er allerede tilmeldt";
            }

            else {
            OleDbCommand Cmd3 = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);
            Cmd3.CommandText = "UPDATE Booking SET Tilmeldte = Tilmeldte+1, Pladser = Pladser-1 WHERE Hold_ID = @Hold_idPar";
            Cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("Hold_idPar", varHold_id);
            Cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OleDbCommand Cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);
            Cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tilmelding (Medlems_id, Hold_ID) VALUES (@Medlems_idPar, @Hold_idPar)";
            Cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Medlems_idPar", Medlems_idva);
            Cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("Hold_idPar", varHold_id);
            Cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();



            Session["RedirectedMessage"] = "Du er tilmeldt holdet" + holdnavn;
            Response.Redirect("Kalender.aspx");
            }
            //Response.Redirect("Kalender.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblmessage.Text = "Der er ikke flere pladser";
        }
    }
    ObjReader.Close();
    MyConn.Close();
}

private object Int32(object p)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}


public string StrCmd { get; set; }
```

Our problem now is that, the members can just keep signing up to the events. But if the event ID and the Member ID are the same, then it works correctly for some reason.

Here is some translation for the database since we used Danish words for naming the DB.

```
    Hold_id=Event_id

    Medlems_id=Member_id
```

Hope you can help us, since our hair is becoming quite gray.

Answer (score 0):

Before insert you can use the below query:

```
select Event_Table.Event_Id from Event_Table inner join Member_Table
on Event_Table.Event_Id=Member_Table.Event_Id
```

and do not sign up the member if Event_Id you selected from the above query matches with event id  in the session.
(Suppose your table containing Events is 'Event_Table' and table containing Member Sign up is 'Member_Table')

Comment: I dont quite follow, Event_table meaning the name of my table containing the events or?